# Do flowers have any purpose?

Tags: minicraft

**This is a question about Minicraft, not Minecraft.**

I can pick up and place flowers on the grass, but do they have any purpose except being pretty?

Comment: For some reason I can't edit this, but it should be 'Do the flowers' and be ended by a '?'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Minicraft wiki page on [flowers](http://minicraftwiki.com/index.php?title=Flower)

> Flowers can only be placed on grass. Each produces a tile that appears to be two flowers. *They have no known use.* Except one...they are very pretty

Comment: there was I thinking you did the same mistake I did... But it's the other way around, you linked to the correct wiki but misspelled MinIcraft in your answer :-7

Comment: Curse the letter 'E'!

Comment: indeed :-) I challenge you to get allong for 24 hours without it, though

Comment: I'll do my utmost.

Comment: good :-) hm, I won't ask you to omitt that char in your autograph... Out of solidarity, this annotation contains no cuss-chars.

Comment: @Pureferret while updating an old answer is appreciated: this question is still about min*i*craft and not min*e*craft =p

Answer (score 2):

No. Since [Minicraft was created within 48 hours](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/14463117193/ludum-dare-is-a-wonderful-thing), only the most essential crafting (tools and weapons) recipes have been implemented. Maybe in the [announced successor](https://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/151339210874437632) they will have uses.