# Minecraft 1.1 and odd boat behavior?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I rarely use boats at all, so I am a bit unfamiliar with them. However, I decided to try out some boat contraptions, and I noticed some really odd behavior. I assumed this was just Minecraft being Minecraft, but it seems that these oddities should not be happening.

1. Boats seem to be blocked by non-solid blocks, like signs.
2. Water elevators seem to (to some extent) work again.

This certainly seems... abnormal. This was tested on Minecraft 1.1 only, so I don't know if any of these bugs were apparent in 1.0, but I don't think they were. Could anyone confirm that these bugs are in fact present in 1.1 and that they were not present in 1.0?

Comment: @Pureferret agreed. But... [aww](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47856/do-flowers-have-any-purpose/47868#comment71393_47868) :-(

Comment: I can't find your bugs on the bug list, on MCwiki. Could to show photos? Perhaps your using mods/in SSP or SMP? @TobiasKienzler better?

Comment: @Pureferret :-) It's difficult, I concur. To stay fair, I'd say "the" and links don't count

Comment: my answer to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12753/how-can-i-make-a-boatlock-in-minecraft proves that a) yes water elevators work again if built properly and b) Signs do not block boats.

Comment: *Every* version has had odd boat behavior.  :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the boat being blocked by signs, is because signs are still a block, and thus you cannot pass through them.

Also, IIRC, water elevators and boats always worked.